# Weighted Average Score

Tags: statistics, scoring, metaheuristics

I have several different scores that I'd like to combine them into a single score that represents all parameters. Score components are:

- Nutrition Score (1-10): 1 for the worst quality and 10 for the best quality
- Processing quality (1-4): 1 for the least processed and 4 for the most processed food
- Some other features with different scaling

```
Overall score = w1 * Nutrition_Score + w2 * Processing_Quality + w3 * parameter_3 + ...
```

Considering that I don't have a mean to measure and distinguish the importance of each of these parameters compared to the rest of them, is there any way to assign weights to each of them except the heuristic way of doing it?

Comment: What will you be using this composite score for and where do you get the values for the features?

Comment: If you have no way to measure the importance of each component of the score, then all you have is your heuristics.